# Javascript console window unavailable

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I can't use my Javascript console window on my Visual Studio 2012. I am able to view it while debugging under Debug > Windows > Javascript Console but it tells me it is unavailable. I am running my Microsoft Visual Studion Premium 2012 Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2 on a 64-bit PC. What seems to be the problem here? :(

Comment: what kind of application are you in?

Comment: I made a navigation app with 7 pages.

Comment: do you have the same problem with the DOM explorer?

Comment: Yes, that too. I am using a remote machine to debug.

Comment: Thank you @Maurizio. Because of the DOM explorer, I tried searching for it too and found out that I have to set debugger type to "Script Only". I've been using "Native Only" the whole time. Thanks for your responses! :)

Comment: that's where I was going :) I had the same problem many times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have you debugger set type to `"Native Only"`.

You shohuld open `"project properties" -> Debugging` and set `"Debugger Type"` to `"Script Only"` to be able to debug Javascript.